# PHPUnit database testing with DBUnit extension

Tags: database, unit-testing, dataset, phpunit, dbunit

Hey, 
Im new to the whole PHPUnit and would like to test my code against a database, from reading all the stuff on the phpunit.de, it talks about a seed.xml file.

Can someone just clarify, do i need to create this dataset myself using a mysqldump command, or does it create it for me at the beginning of the test?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: hey post the link when you get any answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am just now researching this myself and came across this blog post:

http://matthewturland.com/2010/01/04/database-testing-with-phpunit-and-mysql/

So if you choose to accept the PHPUnit >= 3.5.0 requirements, you can use

```
mysqldump --xml -t -u username -p database
```

to create seed.xml and then load it as a dataset for DBUnit with

```
$dataSet = $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet('/path/to/seed.xml');
```

Comment: I've done this and get error messages like `RuntimeException: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE4 0x6B 0x6F 0x77
PCDATA invalid Char value 25
PCDATA invalid Char value 20
PCDATA invalid Char value 12
PCDATA invalid Char value 31
Premature end of data in tag field line 40095
Premature end of data in tag row line 40091
Premature end of data in tag table_data line 40090
Premature end of data in tag database line 3
Premature end of data in tag mysqldump line 2`

Comment: It sounds like your dump file is not valid UTF-8 encoded. Check the encoding of your MySQL database.

Some googling leads me to believe that you can convert the dump file if you know the source encoding by using the iconv utility, see http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Converting_files_to_UTF-8

But I expect things will be a lot easier if you convert your database to use UTF-8 first.